# Repeat a particular row in pandas n no. of times in pandas and increase a count for every repeat in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
df_in = pd.DataFrame([["A","X",5,4,1],["B","Y",3,3,1],["C","Y",4,7,4]], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4','col5'])
```

I want to repeat a row **n** no. of times and the count also should increase from the no. present in col4.

Ex: I want to repeat the B row 3 times and count in col4 will increse from the current value present in col4 like 3,4 and 5. Similarly for C row repeat 2 times and increase the count in col4 from the current value.

Expected Output:

```
df_Out = pd.DataFrame([["A","X",5,4,1],["B","Y",3,3,1],["B","Y",3,4,1],["B","Y",3,5,1],["C","Y",4,7,4],["C","Y",4,8,4]], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4','col5'])
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create dictionary for number of repeating, map by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and if no match set `1`, then use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) for index values with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for append rows, last add counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for `col4`:

```
d = {'B':3, 'C':2}

df = df_in.loc[df_in.index.repeat(df_in['col1'].map(d).fillna(1))]
df['col4'] += df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  col1 col2  col3  col4  col5
0    A    X     5     4     1
1    B    Y     3     3     1
2    B    Y     3     4     1
3    B    Y     3     5     1
4    C    Y     4     7     4
5    C    Y     4     8     4
```